# Pandas DataFrame: Add a list to each cell by iterating over df with new column does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

DataFrame with some columns a and b.
I now want to add a new column c that should contain lists (of different lengths).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[5,6,7]})
new_col_init = [list() for i in range(len(df1)]
df1['c'] = pd.Series(new_col_init,dtype='object')
print(df1)
```

gives:

```
   a  b   c
0  1  5  []
1  2  6  []
2  3  7  []
```

Why Am I unable to do the following:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1.loc[i,'c'] = [2]*i
```

This results in `ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`.

However this works:

```
df1['c'] = pd.Series([[2], [2,2], [2,2,2]])
print(df1)
```

Result:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   5   [2]
1   2   6   [2, 2]
2   3   7   [2, 2, 2]
```

Is there a way to assign the lists by iterating with a for-loop? (I have a lot of other stuff that gets already assigned within that loop and I now need to add the new lists)

Comment: for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1.loc[i,'c'] = str([2]*(i+1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.at`:

```
for i, idx in enumerate(df1.index, 1):
    df1.at[idx, "c"] = [2] * i

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b          c
0  1  5        [2]
1  2  6     [2, 2]
2  3  7  [2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. Whats the actual difference between `.at[]` and `.loc[]`?

Comment: @Crysers `.at` is for acessing single value, `.loc` can access groups of values and can be used with boolean indexing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can try out using [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html#pandas-index-map),

```
df1['c'] = df1.index.map(lambda x: (x + 1) * [2])
```

---

```
   a  b          c
0  1  5        [2]
1  2  6     [2, 2]
2  3  7  [2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[:, 'c'] = [[2]*(i+1) for i in range(len(df1))]
```

Comment: This syntax is really dense. Can you add some text for readers who might not be familiar with `:` used as index or the comprehension you're using?